# 'Suppress someone's voices and opinions' - Word Choices?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

Today, my mom and brother argued about an opinion regarding the cultural problem in our country. When I monitored the conversation, I saw my brother using aggressive voice, tones, and his own opinions rather than calmly stopped talking in order to hear what mom had to say from her perspectives and opinions.

-> I call his act in English 'to suppress someone's voice and opinions with his own opinions', or merely 'suppress someone's opinions with his own perspectives' in this context. For e.g.: 'my brother used aggressive voice and tones to suppress my mom's voice and opinions'.

Is that a correct way to put it in spoken English and in written English?

​
Thank you!​

Answer (score 1):

It's not idiomatic and it's awfully long-winded. It would benefit from being shortened.

What you are saying is that your brother argued aggressively with your mother. To add **voice and tones** is unnecessary as these are taken for granted in any kind of heated discussion.

If you wished to be more specific, you could say that your brother argued aggressively with your mother, shouting her down.

Although we talk about suppressing people's voices or opinions, it's unusual within the context of a family discussion unless you are referring to an authoritarian figure who routinely acts in a despotic manner.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/suppress

Comment: Thanks Ronald. It makes more sense now. Could I ask whether 'shouting' have to be 'shouting'? If my brother just uses lots of sentences to cut between my mom's sentence so that my mom could not talk, is there a word for it?

Comment: @PandoraU.U.D Google ** to shout down**. It means to treat someone just the way that your brother was treating your mother.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. I already searched the word online and learnt that 'shout down' means 'shouting at somebody in a way that prevents that person from speaking out their opinions' !!! But what I was also wondering was what about talking 'a lot' to the point quick and intensively that the other person couldn't speak out to join the discussion